# Populating a second dropdown using ColdFusion, jQuery, and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, coldfusion, multi-select

I have one dropdown that has 14 values. Depending on the value chosen, it'll query a SQL Server database and return some clients to display in a second dropdown.

I want that 2nd dropdown to use the jQuery Multiselect Widget where each value has a checkbox to select.

Here is what I last tried to do, and it just doesn't work.

```
    <form>
        <label for="lstTiers">Tier:</label>  
        <select name="lstTiers" id="lstTiers">    
            <option value="1">Tier 1</option>    
            <option value="2">Tier 2</option>    
            <option value="3">Tier 3</option>  
            <option value="4">Tier 4</option>  
            <option value="5">Tier 5</option>  
            <option value="6">Tier 6</option>  
            <option value="7">Tier 7</option>  
            <option value="8">Tier 8</option>  
            <option value="9">Tier 9</option>  
            <option value="10">Tier 10</option>  
            <option value="11">Tier 11</option>                                                                                                                  
            <option value="12">Tier 12</option>                                                                                                                  
            <option value="13">Tier 13</option>                                                                                                                  
            <option value="14">Tier 14</option>                                                                                                                                                                  
        </select>
        <label for="lstClients">Client:</label>  
        <select name="lstClients" id="lstClients">    
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="click_me" id="click_me" value="Click Me" />
    </form>
```

Here is one attempt at the jQuery:

```
        $('#click_me').click(function() { alert('here');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Ajax-test.cfc?method=returnSomething',
                data: {
                    Tier: $('#lstTiers').val()
                },
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) { 
                    $('#lstClients').html(data);                        
                },

                // This fires when an error with ColdFusion occurs
                error: function() {

                    alert('An error has occured!');

                }

            });

        }); // End click()
```

I had also tried some other jQuery where I looped and built the options.

Finally, here's my cfc file:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cffunction access="remote" name="returnSomething" returntype="query" returnformat="json">
        <cfargument name="Tier" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfquery name="qryGetClients" datasource="ProjectGrid_Test">
            SELECT Div, ClientName FROM tblClientUpgradeClients WHERE Tier = #arguments.Tier# ORDER BY Div
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn qryGetClients>
    <cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

If possible, that returned dropdown should allow user to multiselect using a checkbox. I've played with the jQuery Multiselect widget and I've had it work, but not on this dynamic query.

```
$('#lstClients).multiselect(
        {   noneSelectedText:"All Selected",
            show: ["fade"], 
            hide: ["fade"], 
            selectedList: 1, 
            multiple: true,
            uncheckAllText: ["Clear"]
        });
```

Comment: instead of doing `.html(data)`, you need to convert data to an html string of options. Though, i don't quite understand your sql query... are you really storing <option> in your database?

Comment: No, I am not storing the <option>. I'm really storing the Div and ClientName. I was experimenting and thought maybe my query could build the whole <option>. I had also just queried Div and Clientname and tried to do something like: for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++){ options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue  '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';; ("#lstClients").html(options);
//           }

Comment: Ah, sorry, i miss-interpreted what you were doing in the sql. That makes sense, but i'd still just do that on the client side. The for loop you mentioned would be a common way of doing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried the loop too and I just don't know what I'm doing. I bet it is pretty close, but some syntax error or something. My SQL could very well be just SELECT DIV, ClientName FROM tblClientUpgradeClients WHERE Tier = #arguments.Tier# ORDER BY Div

Comment: It might be easier to use the bind attribute of cfinput instead of using jquery.  However, even if you don't, it's important to make sure your cfc works when called from coldfusion before attempting to call it from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I will do my best to use the vernacular of your coding in this example

note i am using coldfusion 9.0.1 and jquery 1.9+

```
jquery/javascript

           $('#lstTiers').on('change', function (){        
               $.ajax({
               url:'Ajax-test.cfm',
                       data: {'method': 'returnSomething',
                              'Tier': $(this).val(); },

               success: function(json){
                   if (json != '' )
                var vx='<option value="">All</option>';
                   $.each (json, function(k, v){

                       vx+='<option value="'+v.client_id+'">'+v.client_name+'</option>';            
                   });
                   $('#lstClients').html(vx);
                   }

               }); //end ajax()

       });
```

Coldfusion

```
<cffunction name="returnSomething" access="remote" output="false" returntype="json">
<cfargument name="Tier" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfset var qryGetClients= "">
        <cfquery name="qryGetClients" datasource="ProjectGrid_Test">
Select * from Clients WHERE Tier = #arguments.Tier# ORDER BY 1 
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qryGetClients>
</cffunction>
```

heres the thing, you need to see what return type json format is giving you, if it is coldfusion json, you would change the jquery each iteration to `$.each (json.DATA, function(k, v){`

i do things in the MVC way , and like my json to be standard non CF output, so heres an example of my code

controller

```
    <cffunction name="getRequestorsByEvent" access="remote" output="false" returntype="query">
        <cfargument name="nd_event_id" type="string" required="false">  
        <cfargument name="status" type="string" required="false">   
        <cfset var qRequestorsByEvent = "">
        <cfquery datasource="#application.DSN#" name="qRequestorsByEvent">
    select distinct d.init_contact_staff, initcap(e.pref_name_sort) name  from ben_activity_dtl d
    inner join entity e
    on e.id_number = d.init_contact_staff

    where d.nd_event_id =  <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.nd_event_id#">
    <cfif isDefined("arguments.status") and arguments.status neq "">
                                and d.request_status_code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.status#"> 
                            </cfif>
    order by 2 asc    
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn qRequestorsByEvent>
    </cffunction>
```

model

```
<cffunction name="RequestorsByEvent" output="false" hint="index">
    <cfset var rc=event.getcollection()>
    <cfset var returnArray = ArrayNew(1) />
    <cfset qRequestorsByEvent = getmodel("dynform").getRequestorsByEvent(rc.nd_event_id, Event.getValue("status", ''))> 
     <cfloop query="qRequestorsByEvent">
        <cfset RequestorsStruct = StructNew() />
        <cfset RequestorsStruct["init_contact_staff"] = init_contact_staff/>
        <cfset RequestorsStruct["name"] = name />

        <cfset ArrayAppend(returnArray,RequestorsStruct) />
    </cfloop>        

    <cfset event.renderData( type="json", data=returnArray ) />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Well, I took your code and tried it, and it doesn't work for me. I did change my query to SELECT Div, ClientName FROM tblClientUpgradeClients WHERE Tier = #arguments.Tier#. And I changed it to vx+='<option value="'+v.Div+'">'+v.ClientNmae+'</option>';  I just get an error.

Comment: Oh, I get a 'Div' is null or not an object. But it depends on what option I pick. I don't even know if it's bringing back any data.

Comment: A direct link to your cf function should return a json result set , take the same link your using for ajax url param and post what is being returned

Answer (score 1):

Try that using cfcomponent and cfselect tag.

The below link may be useful.

http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/31/ColdFusion-Ajax-Tutorial-2-Related-Selects